# Create Jenkins Job when a new GitHub Repository is detected

Tags: java, github, jenkins, automation

If a specified user/organization creates a new repository, is there a way for Jenkins to make a job based on some form of template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [GitHub Webhooks, Events](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#events):

> | `repository` | Any time a Repository is created, deleted (organization hooks only), made public, or made private. |

See [Jenkins Plugin: create a new job programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322179/jenkins-plugin-create-a-new-job-programmatically) or [Remote access API](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API):

> Remote API can be used to do things like these:
>
> 1. ...
> 2. ...
> 3. create/copy jobs

Open `http://Your Jenkins/api` for further information:

> #### Create Job
>
> To create a new job, post `config.xml` to [this URL](http://Your_Jenkins/createItem) [`http://Your Jenkins/createItem`] ...

See also [Job Generator Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Job+Generator+Plugin):

> This plugin is a good fit for generating pipelines based on parameterized templates.

Comment: As always with Jenkins, it looks like there's no one-stop-shop to address this issue. But this all has pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!